# How to Count items in nested collection / codefirst EntityFramework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I've got CodeFirst collection defined as defined below.

For any given EmailOwnerId, I want to count the number of EmailDetailAttachments records exist without actually downloading all the images themselves.

I know I can do something like

```
var emailsToView = (from data in db.EmailDetails.Include("EmailDetailAttachments")
                        where data.EmailAccount.EmailOwnerId = 999
                        select data).ToList();
int cnt = 0;    
foreach (var email in emailsToView)
{
     cnt += email.EmailDetailAttachments.Count();
}
```

but that means I've already downloaded all the bytes of images from my far away server.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
public class EmailDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmailOwnerId {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ImageDetail> EmailDetailAttachments { get; set; }
    ..
}

public class ImageDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLengthAttribute(256)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MaxLengthAttribute(256)]
    public string ContentMimeType { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageDataBytes { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImageCreation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The engine should be able to update this to a `COUNT(*)` statement.

```
  var emailsToView = (from data in db.EmailDetails  // no Include
                    where data.EmailAccount.EmailOwnerId = 999
                    select new { 
                      Detail = data, 
                      Count=data.EmailDetailAttachments.Count() }
                     ).ToList();
```

But you'll have to verify if this produces the right (and more efficient) SQL.

Comment: Thanks Henk, great technique. I'll definitely use this in the future.  I had not thought of that.